# Why is it that I cannot filter() out elements using loops?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter out elements in arr that are equal to the input arguments. I was wondering why this wouldn't work.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values
var newarr = arr.slice();
var i = 1;
while (i < arguments.length){
 newarr = newarr.filter(function(num){
  if (num == arguments[i]){
    return (false);
  }
  return (true);
  });
  i++;
}
 return newarr;
}
```

destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5);

should return [1];

The way I solved it was using splice() instead:

```
 function destroyer(arr) {
  var i = 1;
  while (i < arguments.length){
    var j = 0;
    while (j < arr.length){
      if (arr[j] == arguments[i]){
        arr.splice(j,1);
        j = j;
      }
      else
        j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is: in the following code:

```
 newarr = newarr.filter(function(num){
  if (num == arguments[i]){
    return (false);
   }
   return (true);
 });
```

The `arguments` is not what you expected. `arguments` here refer to the parameters of `function(num){...`, not the parameters of `destroyer(arr)`.

To fix the problem, you can retrieve the interested number before `newarr.filter`:

```js
    function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
      var newarr = arr.slice();
      var i = 1;
      while (i < arguments.length){
        var interested = arguments[i];
        newarr = newarr.filter(function(num){
          if (num == interested){
            return (false);
          }
          return (true);
        });
        i++;
      }
      return newarr;
    }

    console.log(destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5));
```

Comment: ahhh i see. That makes sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simpler way

```js
function destroyer() {
    let args = Array.from(arguments); // Create new array from the arguments
        args.shift(); // remove first element from the arguments
    return arguments[0].filter( item => !args.includes(item) ); //Doing  filter
}

console.log(destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5)); // [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are not using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

For example:

```js
const elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const filterInput = inputs => element => !inputs.includes(element);

const filteredElements = elements.filter(filterInput([1, 5, 6]));

console.log(filteredElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `arguments` variable in another function,

`if (num == arguments[i]){` the arguments variable that's here is actullay arguments list of second function.

```
function(num){
  if (num == arguments[i]){
    return (false);
  }
  return (true);
}
```

to fix this problem try this:

```
 function destroyer(arr) {
  var i = 1,
  args = arguments;
  while (i < arguments.length){
    var j = 0;
    while (j < arr.length){
      if (arr[j] == args[i]){
        arr.splice(j,1);
        j = j;
      }
      else
        j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}
```